# How to adjust the "Total Price" whenever I change the input values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I add an item to the cart, the item appends to the row in the shopping cart, and the price will adjust. But I am having some trouble having the price adjusting to whenever I change the inputs (input: "type" = number) values. I cannot seem to find the correct format. Can I have some assistance? Feedback is much appreciated. Here to learn!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>E-Commerce Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="p1" id="p1">
            <div class="topnavcont">
                <ul class="topleftnav">
                <a href="#p1"><li class="topnavlink">Home</li></a>
                <a href="#p2"><li class="topnavlink">Shop</li></a>
            </ul>
            <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
            <div class="navcartcontainer">
                <h3 class="totalnumber">0</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"> -->
            
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="clark-street-mercantile-P3pI6xzovu0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"><div class="overlay"></div></div>

                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="michela-ampolo-7tDGb3HrITg-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"><div class="overlay"></div></div>

                    <!-- <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    ... -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- If we need pagination -->
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                
                    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev arrow"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next arrow"></div>
                
                    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
                    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="cartbody">
                <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
                <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
                <ul class="cartitems">
                    <!-- <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div> -->
                </ul>
                <h3 class="actualprice carttotal"id="actualprice">Total: $0</h3>
                <button class="purchasebtn" id="purchasebtn">Purchase</button>
                
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="p2" id="p2">
    <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
    <div class="itemcontainer">
<div class="item">
    <img src="anomaly-WWesmHEgXDs-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">White Shirt</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="revolt-164_6wVEHfI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Red Shoes</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$4.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="sebastian-coman-travel-dtOTQYmTEs0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Sunglasses</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>
    <div class="itemcontainer2">
<div class="item">
    <img src="haley-phelps-RgJ-NU_qWjM-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Jeans</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$1.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="olive-tatiane-ImEzF9B91Mk-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Necklace</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="rafael-silva-fc2Q2DKBCYY-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Beanie</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$2.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>

</div>


    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.topnavcont{
    padding: 1em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.topleftnav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: -3%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.topleftnav li{
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}
.topleftnav li:hover{
    border-bottom: black solid 2px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.topnavtitle{
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.navcartcontainer{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -1%;
    
}
.topnavcont .totalnumber{
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    height: fit-content;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i{
    font-size: 2rem; 
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    
}
.topnavcont i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.p1{
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p1 img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.p1 .overlay::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.cartbody{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 25vw;
    top: 10%;
    left: 75%;
    z-index: 2100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
}
.carttotal{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.purchasebtn{
    background-color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding: 1em 2.5em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.purchasebtn:hover{
    background-color: rgb(11, 70, 75);
}
.cartbody i{
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.cartbody i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.cartbody input{
    width: 2.2rem;
    height: auto;
}
.cartbodyactive{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: white;
}
.carttitle{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.cartitem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.cartitem .itemtitle{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.cartitems{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 3em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.removebtn{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.p2{
    height: 120vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p2title{
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
.p2 img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.itemcontainer{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.itemcontainer2{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 355px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn{
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.atcbtn:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.arrow{
    color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .topnavcont{
        padding: 1em 0em;
        align-items: center;
        height: 10vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    
    
    .topleftnav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        width: 55%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 5%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .topleftnav li{
        cursor: pointer;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 1rem;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
        border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
    }
    .topleftnav li:hover{
        border-bottom: black solid 2px;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    .topnavtitle{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .navcartcontainer{
        display: flex;
        padding-right: 5%;
        margin-left: 0%;
        
    }
    .topnavcont .totalnumber{
        color: black;
        padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        height: fit-content;
        /* cursor: pointer; */
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .topnavcont i{
        font-size: 2rem; 
        margin-left: 0.3em;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.4s ease;
        
    }

    .cartbody{
        background-color: white;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 80vw;
        top: 10%;
        left: 20%;
        z-index: 2100;
        overflow-y: auto;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: 0.6s ease;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
    
    }
    .carttotal{
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 3em;
    }
    .cartbody i{
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        margin-left: 0.4em;
        margin-top: 0.2em;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 200;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
    .cartbody i:hover{
        transform: scale(1.15);
    }
    .cartbody input{
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: auto;
    }
    .cartbodyactive{
        transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: white;
    }
    .carttitle{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    .cartitem{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
    }
    .cartitem .itemtitle{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    .cartitems{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        row-gap: 3em;
        overflow-y: auto;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .removebtn{
        background-color: red;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .p2{
        height: fit-content;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .p2title{
        color: black;
        padding-top: 2.5em;
        margin-left: 7%;
    }
    .p2 img{
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .itemcontainer{
        margin-top: 6em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .itemcontainer2{
        margin-top: 6em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 355px;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
    }
    
    .atcbtn{
        background-color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        width: 40%;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: black solid 2px;
        padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
        transition: 0.4s ease;
    }
    .atcbtn:hover{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .arrow{
        color: white;
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    let TotalNumber = document.querySelector(".totalnumber");
    const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName("atcbtn");
    const cartbtn = document.getElementById("cartbtn");
    const closeicon = document.getElementById("closeicon");
    const cartbody = document.querySelector(".cartbody");
    const removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("removebtn");
    const carttotal = document.querySelector(".carttotal");
    let price = document.querySelector(".actualprice");
    let itempricestring = document.getElementsByClassName("itemprice");
    let globalquantinput = document.querySelector(".qinput");

    cartbtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    cartbody.classList.toggle("cartbodyactive");
    });

    closeicon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    cartbody.classList.remove("cartbodyactive");
    });

    function AddItemtoCart() {
  //INCREASING THE TOTAL NUMBER
    for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++) {
        let button = Atc[i];
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML;
        if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {
            TotalNumber.innerHTML++;
        }

        //GETTING THE SHOP ELEMENTS AND APPENDING THEM TO THE CART
        let shopitem = button.parentElement;
        let shoptitle =
            shopitem.getElementsByClassName("item-title")[0].innerText;
        let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
        shoppriceall = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice").innerText;
        let cartrow = document.createElement("div");
        let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems")[0];
        let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`;
        cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent;
        cartitems.append(cartrow);

        //ADJUSTING THE TOTAL
        let priceint = price.innerText;
        let pricerounded = parseFloat(priceint.replace("Total: $", ""));

        let shopprice2 = shopprice.replace("$", "");
        let shoppriceint = parseFloat(shopprice2);
        console.log(shoppriceint);
        console.log(pricerounded);

        price.innerText = "Total: $" + (shoppriceint + pricerounded).toFixed(2);

        //REMOVING ELEMENTS AND DECREASING NUMBER
        cartitems.lastChild
            .querySelector(".removebtn")
            .addEventListener("click", function () {
            let TotalNumbervalue = parseInt(TotalNumber.innerText);
            console.log(TotalNumbervalue);
            if (TotalNumbervalue > 0) {
                let shopremoveitem = this.parentElement.parentElement;
                let shopremoveprice =
                shopremoveitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
                let shopremoveprice2 = shopremoveprice.replace("$", "");
                let shopremovepriceint = parseFloat(shopremoveprice2);
                let quantin = document.querySelector(".qinput");
                let quantinval = quantin.value;
                let priceafteradded = parseFloat(
                price.innerText.replace("Total: $", "")
                );
                TotalNumber.innerText--;
                Math.round(shopremovepriceint);

                price.innerText =
                "Total: $" +
                (priceafteradded - shopremovepriceint * quantinval).toFixed(2);
            }
            this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            });

        //PRICEINT1 PRICEINT2 AND PRICEINT3 ARE TO GET THE INNER TEXT OF THE PRICE IN EACH FUNCTION.

        //MAKING SURE THE INPUTS DONT GO OVER 1 AND ALSO MAKING SURE THEY WORK
        let qinput = document.getElementsByClassName("qinput");

        for (let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++) {
            let qinputnumber = document.querySelector(".qinput");

            //HERE IS THE ISSUE //

            
            qinput[i].addEventListener("change", function () {
            //UPDATE THE PRICE TOTAL ON CHANGE
            let priceint3 = document.querySelector(".actualprice").innerText;
            let newqinput = cartrow.getElementsByClassName("qinput")[0];
            let newqinputval = newqinput.value;
            let priceint3rounded = parseFloat(priceint3.replace("Total: $", ""));

            price.innerText =
                "Total: $" +
                (priceint3rounded + shoppriceint * newqinputval).toFixed(2);

            //MAKE SURE NUMBERS DONT GO BELOW 1
            if (qinput[i].value < 1) {
                qinput[i].value = 1;
                price.innerText = priceint3;
            }
            });

            if (qinput[i].value > 1) {
            qinput[i].value = qinputnumber.value;
            } else {
            qinput[i].value = 1;
            }
        }
        });
    }
    }

    //ALERTING USER THAT ITEMS HAVE BEEN PURCHASED
    AddItemtoCart();

    let purchasebtn = document.getElementById("purchasebtn");
    purchasebtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    location.reload();
    alert("Your items have been purchased!");
    });

    //SMOOTH SCROLL
    const scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
    speed: 1000,
    speedAsDuration: true,
    easing: "easeinquad",
    });
    //SWIPER
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: "horizontal",
    loop: true,
    speed: 300,
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        dynamicBullets: true,
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },

    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar: {
        el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    },
});
```

Comment: Your code would need some serious refactoring. One of the problems I see is that you're reusing the `id` attribute among multiple elements, which is not allowed and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Also, I'd consider using React or something else, it would make your UI code so much cleaner.

Comment: There is a lot of code there. If you are able to provide a minimal example of what you are trying to do we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add the price of an object every time you change the amount of it.

So if you have "Red Shoes" in your Cart and the price is at 4.99$

If you now click the up button or increase the value of the input field by one another `shoppriceint * newqinputval` is added to the OLD-total so the price displayed now is $14.97 (eg. 4.99 initial price + 2 * shoppriceint)

You would have to store the current amount before the change happened (onfoucs or something simmilar) and then substract it before you add another 2 items on top:

```
(priceint3rounded - shoppriceint * oldqinputval + shoppriceint * newqinputval).toFixed(2);
```

Hope this helped.
Have a great day! If you need further assistance let me know (:

Answer (score 0):

Here's the part I updated, removing the code around it that was trying to do the same thing before:

```
function updateAmounts() {
  let total = 0
  document.querySelectorAll(".qinput").forEach(el => {
    let qty = +el.value
    let price = +el.closest('.cartitem').querySelector('.itemprice').innerText.trim().replace('$','');
    total += (qty * price);
  })
  document.querySelector(".actualprice").innerHTML = `Total: $${total.toFixed(2)}`
}
document.querySelectorAll(".qinput").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", (e) =>  updateAmounts()))
```

What this does is:

- every time a `.qinput` field is changed (a quantity)
- it triggers `updateAmounts()`, which
- cycles through ALL the `.qinput` fields, finds their respective prices, and tallies the (quantity * price) for each, culminating in the total

```js
let TotalNumber = document.querySelector(".totalnumber");
const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName("atcbtn");
const cartbtn = document.getElementById("cartbtn");
const closeicon = document.getElementById("closeicon");
const cartbody = document.querySelector(".cartbody");
const removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("removebtn");
const carttotal = document.querySelector(".carttotal");
let price = document.querySelector(".actualprice");
let itempricestring = document.getElementsByClassName("itemprice");
let globalquantinput = document.querySelector(".qinput");

cartbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cartbody.classList.toggle("cartbodyactive");
});

closeicon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  cartbody.classList.remove("cartbodyactive");
});

function AddItemtoCart() {
  //INCREASING THE TOTAL NUMBER
  for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++) {
    let button = Atc[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML;
      if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {
        TotalNumber.innerHTML++;
      }

      //GETTING THE SHOP ELEMENTS AND APPENDING THEM TO THE CART
      let shopitem = button.parentElement;
      let shoptitle =
        shopitem.getElementsByClassName("item-title")[0].innerText;
      let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
      shoppriceall = shopitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice").innerText;
      let cartrow = document.createElement("div");
      let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName("cartitems")[0];
      let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`;
      cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent;
      cartitems.append(cartrow);

      //ADJUSTING THE TOTAL
      let priceint = price.innerText;
      let pricerounded = parseFloat(priceint.replace("Total: $", ""));

      let shopprice2 = shopprice.replace("$", "");
      let shoppriceint = parseFloat(shopprice2);
      console.log(shoppriceint);
      console.log(pricerounded);

      price.innerText = "Total: $" + (shoppriceint + pricerounded).toFixed(2);

      //REMOVING ELEMENTS AND DECREASING NUMBER
      cartitems.lastChild
        .querySelector(".removebtn")
        .addEventListener("click", function() {
          let TotalNumbervalue = parseInt(TotalNumber.innerText);
          console.log(TotalNumbervalue);
          if (TotalNumbervalue > 0) {
            let shopremoveitem = this.parentElement.parentElement;
            let shopremoveprice =
              shopremoveitem.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0].innerText;
            let shopremoveprice2 = shopremoveprice.replace("$", "");
            let shopremovepriceint = parseFloat(shopremoveprice2);
            let quantin = document.querySelector(".qinput");
            let quantinval = quantin.value;
            let priceafteradded = parseFloat(
              price.innerText.replace("Total: $", "")
            );
            TotalNumber.innerText--;
            Math.round(shopremovepriceint);

            price.innerText =
              "Total: $" +
              (priceafteradded - shopremovepriceint * quantinval).toFixed(2);
          }
          this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        });

      //PRICEINT1 PRICEINT2 AND PRICEINT3 ARE TO GET THE INNER TEXT OF THE PRICE IN EACH FUNCTION.

      //MAKING SURE THE INPUTS DONT GO OVER 1 AND ALSO MAKING SURE THEY WORK
      let qinput = document.getElementsByClassName("qinput");

      for (let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++) {
        let qinputnumber = document.querySelector(".qinput");

        // UPDATED CODE //


        function updateAmounts() {
          let total = 0
          document.querySelectorAll(".qinput").forEach(el => {
            let qty = +el.value
            let price = +el.closest('.cartitem').querySelector('.itemprice').innerText.trim().replace('$', '');
            total += (qty * price);
          })
          document.querySelector(".actualprice").innerHTML = `Total: $${total.toFixed(2)}`
        }
        document.querySelectorAll(".qinput").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", (e) => updateAmounts()))



        if (qinput[i].value > 1) {
          qinput[i].value = qinputnumber.value;
        } else {
          qinput[i].value = 1;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

//ALERTING USER THAT ITEMS HAVE BEEN PURCHASED
AddItemtoCart();

let purchasebtn = document.getElementById("purchasebtn");
purchasebtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  location.reload();
  alert("Your items have been purchased!");
});

//SMOOTH SCROLL
const scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
  speed: 1000,
  speedAsDuration: true,
  easing: "easeinquad",
});
//SWIPER
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: "horizontal",
  loop: true,
  speed: 300,
  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    dynamicBullets: true,
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
  },
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.topnavcont {
  padding: 1em 0em;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.topleftnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: -3%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topleftnav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}

.topleftnav li:hover {
  border-bottom: black solid 2px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.topnavtitle {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.navcartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -1%;
}

.topnavcont .totalnumber {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: fit-content;
  /* cursor: pointer; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.topnavcont i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.p1 {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.p1 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.p1 .overlay::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.cartbody {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
  top: 10%;
  left: 75%;
  z-index: 2100;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
}

.carttotal {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.purchasebtn {
  background-color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  padding: 1em 2.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 35%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.purchasebtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(11, 70, 75);
}

.cartbody i {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  margin-left: 0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.cartbody i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

.cartbody input {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: auto;
}

.cartbodyactive {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: white;
}

.carttitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.cartitem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.cartitem .itemtitle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.cartitems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 3em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.removebtn {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.p2 {
  height: 120vh;
  position: relative;
}

.p2title {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

.p2 img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.itemcontainer {
  margin-top: 6em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.itemcontainer2 {
  margin-top: 6em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 355px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: black solid 2px;
  padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.atcbtn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.arrow {
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnavcont {
    padding: 1em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .topleftnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 55%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .topleftnav li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
  }
  .topleftnav li:hover {
    border-bottom: black solid 2px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  .topnavtitle {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navcartcontainer {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .topnavcont .totalnumber {
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    height: fit-content;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .topnavcont i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
  }
  .cartbody {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 2100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;
  }
  .carttotal {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
  .cartbody i {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .cartbody i:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  .cartbody input {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: auto;
  }
  .cartbodyactive {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: white;
  }
  .carttitle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .cartitem {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .cartitem .itemtitle {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .cartitems {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 3em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
  }
  .removebtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .p2 {
    height: fit-content;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .p2title {
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 7%;
  }
  .p2 img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .itemcontainer {
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .itemcontainer2 {
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 355px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .atcbtn {
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
  }
  .atcbtn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .arrow {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="p1" id="p1">
    <div class="topnavcont">
      <ul class="topleftnav">
        <a href="#p1">
          <li class="topnavlink">Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#p2">
          <li class="topnavlink">Shop</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
      <div class="navcartcontainer">
        <h3 class="totalnumber">0</h3>
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg"> -->

    <div class="swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="clark-street-mercantile-P3pI6xzovu0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="michela-ampolo-7tDGb3HrITg-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                    ... -->
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev arrow"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next arrow"></div>

      <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
      <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cartbody">
      <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
      <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
      <ul class="cartitems">
        <!-- <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div>
                    <div><li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li></div> -->
      </ul>
      <h3 class="actualprice carttotal" id="actualprice">Total: $0</h3>
      <button class="purchasebtn" id="purchasebtn">Purchase</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="p2" id="p2">
    <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
    <div class="itemcontainer">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="anomaly-WWesmHEgXDs-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">White Shirt</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="revolt-164_6wVEHfI-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Red Shoes</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$4.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="sebastian-coman-travel-dtOTQYmTEs0-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Sunglasses</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="itemcontainer2">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="haley-phelps-RgJ-NU_qWjM-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Jeans</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$1.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="olive-tatiane-ImEzF9B91Mk-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Necklace</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$6.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="rafael-silva-fc2Q2DKBCYY-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
        <h1 class="item-title">Beanie</h1>
        <h3 class="itemprice">$2.99</h3>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
        <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" async></script>
```